# Nested Eclipse Form sections

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am experimenting with form sections. Is there a way to add a section within a section in a form?

The form layout I am trying to achieve is the following:

> **>** Personal Info
>
> **V** Educational Info
>
> > **>** Qualification 1
> >
> > **>** Qualification 2
>
> **>** Employment History

(**>** - collapsed section, **V** expanded section)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the SWT sections with `Section.TWISTIE` style bit set, as described in this IBM article "[Customizing Eclipse RCP applications (Techniques to use with SWT and JFace)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-rcp1/section10.html)".

That allows you to define GUI like:

[image]

The other alternative is to use an Eclipse Form (presented in this "[Eclipse Forms: Rich UI for the Rich Client](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html)" article) based on **`ExpandableComposite`**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks VonC,

I am looking to have a section within a section. Is that achievable?

e:g:

Can the **Qualification 1** and **Qualification 2** sections
be children of **Educational info** Section, so that when educational section collapses the Qualification 1 and Qualification 2 sections will be hidden.

```
> Personal Info

V Educational Info

        > Qualification 1

        > Qualification 2

> Employment History
```